# Facebook API - access user events

Tags: facebook, api, events

I created a test app on Facebook.

I chose to request access to user events for API calls.

I then connected my user properly through api, I can get user details by oauth key for this particular user, but I can't access user events.

From the tools that FB provides, I seem to be able to access the user events, but the oauth key used in the call is different from the one FB gave me back for this user.

What did I miss?

Comment: seems like the preview oauth panel from FB app view shows that the app will access user events. but when I connect the user from the app to the real FB user, it just says that the app will access basic info and no events... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Submit the access token to the [Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and verify it contains the `user_events` permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realized that specifying scopes only within the app setting panel wasn't enough.

For each new oauth call for users, need to specify the list of scopes you want to authorize the key for.

All working good now.